# Is it a security issue that Nginx returns server name in errors?

Tags: http, webserver, header

I have recently sat up an Nginx in a way that makes it not return a `Server` header and hide the version information from the error pages.

The error page looks like that now (and anyone can provoke it by sending wrong HTTP request very easily):

[image]

The question is really if it is enough? Or to be more precise:

1. Is disclosing the information that one runs Nginx is an issue?
2. If it is how can it be hidden, since it's probably not that hard even without this obvious html to figure out by sending specially crafted requests and responses, probably even som version range can be unveiled by this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, because the information being leaked is so minimal that an attacker gains no meaningful information from it. If you look at today's server landscape, [nginx is currently the most popular web server there is](https://hexometer.com/most-popular-tech-stacks/Web+Servers). So even if an attacker would not know for sure what web server you use, they could simply feel lucky and try some nginx-specific exploits.

The real issue would be if you would run an outdated nginx version with known vulnerabilities.

---

I'd like to clarify some points regarding information disclosure and security through obscurity. Revealing the version information is in itself no vulnerability. It just makes it easier for the attacker, as they don't blindly have to try exploits until one of them works.

**If you believe that hiding version information is security through obscurity**, then you are in a way right. If you run a vulnerable web application, hiding the version will not protect you more. But also, hiding the version will make it more time-consuming for the attacker to actually exploit you, which means you do have some security benefit.

**If you believe that hiding the version information is best-practice**, then you are in a way right. There is no benefit for you in revealing that information, but it's also not a big deal either. If your web server is configured to display version information, then don't freak out. As long as your server is safe, you will be fine.

Comment: Would not that be a problem regardless of exposing version? Attackers as you say would feel lucky and try it anyway :) Of course you don't want to welcome them, but hiding version is hardly a real improvement

Comment: By hiding the version info, you at least stop attackers from applying effective filters. If they know your nginx version is 1.10.1, then they can get a pretty good idea of what attacks would work and what would not.

Comment: @IlyaChernomordik I edited my question to clarify this point.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and clarification! :)

Comment: It's possible perhaps to get the version information by performing very specific requests and observing how the server responds. So it seems as you say not a big deal, but if one can easily hide version, there is no point in showing it either I guess :)

Answer (score 2):

1. No, because you can run fingerprinting software to identify the web server software. Each web server comes with some uniqueness, so hiding your web server's name is security by obscurity.
2. For removing the server header completely, you need to compile nginx yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Wouldn't that fingerprint software identify possible versions regardless of it being exposed? I mean it's probably not a big update to remove version of nginx at all

Comment: @IlyaChernomordik Yes fingerprinting may reveal version information if you try to hide it from output. The idea is to force attackers to perform the version fingerprinting, which may be noisy enough to trip your IDS.